# Importing excel data to the dataset tables C#

Tags: c#, .net

How to import data from excel sheet to dataset in the following code because when I do not name the sheet name to be 'Cost', the dataset displays null. Otherwise, it is ok. I should not put dataSet.Tables["Cost"] cost on this. How to get data from sheet of any name? Thank you in advance.

```
     void ImportData(string fileName)
    {
        //Parsing excel file data
        var dataSet = Common.ParseExcelFile(fileName);

        var cost = dataSet.Tables["Cost"];
        if (cost != null && cost.Rows.Count > 0 )
        {
            BulkInsertCost(cost);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, if the `Common.ParseExcelFile` is inside an assembly you have access to edit, make sure you are setting the `DataTable.TableName` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataSet's `Tables` property has a [numeric indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTableCollection_Item_System_Int32_) as well which you can use to access the tables without knowing their names. e.g.:

```
var cost = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Saeb Amini, you saved my time.